# "Would you mind not to do something?"

Tags: grammar, american-english

I have had this question for a long time and I couldn't find any answers for it. I have often heard this sentence from an American interlocutor and also in some movies:

> "Would you mind not to do something?"

I would like to know if it is correct to use this sentence in this way.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Danesh. I invite you to visit and support the proposed [English Language Learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) site, too.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is wrong to say:

> Would you mind not to do that?

That must be worded this way:

> Would you mind not doing that?

This is one of those places where it actually makes a critical difference whether a *to*-infinitive or an *-ing* form is used.   The infinitive is not allowed here for this particular construction of *to mind* plus a VP. Not all VPs are interchangeable.  You need the *-ing* version.

Comment: What exactly does *the infinitive is **not allowed** here for this particular construction* mean? All I can see is we *don't* say it because we don't hear it from other people. Is there some rule (or even *principle*) allowing the infinitive in closely-related constructions involving, for example, *wish, care, like*, but not with the specific verb *to mind*? I think it's just idiomatic.

Comment: I do not believe there is a general rule, only the lexical rule that "_mind_ subcategorises for a gerund, not a to-infinitive". Many verbs subcategorise for particular objects, in no predictable way.

Comment: @Colin: [Among others](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22should+not+mind+to+die%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), Florence B. Hyett's "Fifty Christmas Poems for Children" (1923) - *I should not mind to die for them, my own dear downs, my comrades true. But that great heart of Bethlehem, he died for men he never knew.* Doggerel maybe, but it certainly doesn't sound ridiculous to me. Saying *"**mind** subcategorises for a gerund* means nothing to me except "that's how we usually use this verb".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  There are lexical rules as well as grammatical rules, and a rule may be narrow or broad. Some people don't like calling them "rules", because this somehow implies loathéd "prescriptivism". But all language is rules. Which is not to say rules don't change, or that every rule obtains in all circumstances and registers.

Comment: @StoneyB: Perhaps we're just splitting hairs over terminology, but I can't see any way to phrase a "rule" in this case that amounts to anything other than something along the lines of *[unlike many similar verbs,] **mind** isn't normally used with an infinitive clause as the object*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: it doesn't sound _ridiculous_ to me, but it is syntactically odd, and I would certainly class it as a poetic usage there, for the purposes of rhythm. You're also right that my hifalutin phrase doesn't mean much more than yours; but I think it it does mean a little more. There is a difference between a lexical rule, which is unpredictable in any given case but fits into a general pattern of such rules (eg subcategorisation), and a pure idiom which is completely _sui generis_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  "*To mind* takes a NP or an *-ing* VP as its object." That's the rule. You can break it for local effect and find that accepted as a nonce-usage, or people may look at you oddly. You may even launch a new idiom - a rule change. But for now it's the rule.

Comment: @Colin: Hmm. So *mind* fits into the same subcategory as *stop* rather than *start* when we're talking about verbs expressing the relationship of subject to action. *Will you start working/to work?* are both fine, as is *Will you stop working?*. I just don't see how "predictable" it is to know that **Will you stop to work?* isn't normally used.

Comment: No, I said it's unpredictable; but it does fit into a pattern of such rules, even though you don't know which is going to apply in a particular case. Compare pluralisation in English, where there are some common rules, some minor rules (eg Greek -a, plurals in -en) and some one-off wierdos (eg woman). You can't tell without knowing it that "phenomenon" will have a plural in "-a", but it does fit into a rule. And your point about "that's how we say it" is equally applicable for these.

Comment: @StoneyB: *"**To reach consensus** is all I seek"*, but the infinitive there looks pretty much like a noun phrase to me. I know you can say *"Ah! But that's an **infinitive phrase**"*, but in most contexts (including my first sentence here) they perform much the same syntactic function. Anyway, I've yet to see any articulation of a "rule" here that amounts to anything more than just *that's the established usage*. Which probably explains why non-native speakers can get this one wrong - *they can't fit it into a pattern*.

Comment: Complementizer choice, as well everything else about a subject or object [complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complementtypes.pdf), is governed by the matrix predicate. In this case, _mind_ governs a gerund [object complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) with [A-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), and doesn't allow an infinitive complement. These are simple grammatical facts, like subject-verb agreement. I don't really understand what all the fuss is about.

Comment: @John Lawler: Yes, but is there a *reason* why "mind governs a gerund object complement with A-Equi", but that constraint doesn't apply to what look to me like closely-related verbs that *do* allow an infinitive complement? If there's no complement at all, *"I don't mind/care"* are interchangeable. Why does one require a gerund, and the other an infinitive, when adding a complement?

Comment: If there is a reason, it's unknown. You might as well try to explain the Syntax Lab reports on various predicates in the answers at the end the [Equi link](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf). Every predicate has its own set of predilections, options, alternations, affordances, and prohibitions, and the closer you look at them, the more you can see their individual grammatical idiosyncracies. Arbitrariness is the rule, not the exception.

Answer (score 0):

OP's construction is *extremely* "non-standard". Many instances in the first page of results from Google Books for ["would you mind to"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22mind%20not%20to%20do%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22would%20you%20mind%20to%22&oq=%22would%20you%20mind%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3...66754.72807.1.73236.14.14.0.0.0.3.144.1447.8j6.14.0...0.0...1c.1.9GuiP02WpBw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bGE&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1343&bih=897) are language guides citing it as an example of incorrect usage, and several others appear to be from non-native speakers anyway.

I don't think there's any grammatical rule in play here - there's no fundamental difference between *mind* and, for example, *care*. And we certainly say *"Would you **care** to do that?"* - although in the *negative*, native speakers invariably prefer *"**Would you mind not doing that?**"* rather than *"Would you **care not** to do that?"* (but you could use *wish* there without raising eyebrows).

Perhaps *because* it's a construction primarily used in "polite/formal" requests, native speakers may be extra careful to take note of and replicate the exact form used by others. Which makes the "idiomatic preference" particularly strong in this case.

---

EDIT: I don't know why all this answer has collected so far is a downvote. I admit [this example](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22should%20not%20mind%20to%20die%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22should%20not%20mind%20to%20die%22&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=5JbQUL6fCNGV0QWYpYGIBA&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1343&bih=897)...

> I should **not mind to die** for them, my own dear downs, my comrades true.
>
> But that great heart of Bethlehem, he died for men he never knew.

...is effectively "doggerel", but I don't think it would have been published at all if it had been considered blatantly ungrammatical.